# Vertical header with SLDS

Tags: visualforce, css, lightning-design-system

I have a table with the following markup. I want the table headers to be in vertical direction. Is there any inbuilt SLDS CSS class to achieve this behavior or do we need to create our own styles from scratch to achieve this. I tried adding CSS to rotate the text but it doesn't work with the inbuilt styles

```
<apex:page readOnly="true" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" 
       applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" lang="en">        
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Student Matrix</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <!-- Import the Design System style sheet -->
        <apex:slds />

        <style>
        .subjectHeader {
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
            transform-origin: left top;
            -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -ms-transform-origin:left top;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -webkit-transform-origin:left top;
        }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="slds-scope">
            <div class="dynamicTable">
                <table class="print-table slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--fixed-layout slds-table--col-bordered" role="grid">
                    <tr class="slds-line-height_reset" style="color:blue">
                        <th scope="col" rowSpan="2">First Name</th>
                        <th scope="col" rowSpan="2">Last Name</th>
                        <th scope="col" rowSpan="2">Email</th>
                        <th scope="col" colSpan="3" style="text-align:center">Semester 1</th>
                        <th scope="col" colSpan="3" style="text-align:center">Semester 2</th>
                        <th scope="col" colSpan="3" style="text-align:center">Semester 3</th>
                        <th scope="col" colSpan="3" style="text-align:center">Semester 4</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="slds-line-height_reset" style="color:blue">
                        <th scope="col" class="subjectHeader slds-cell-wrap">
                            <span class="subjectHeader slds-truncate" title="Physics">Physics</span>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" class="subjectHeader slds-cell-wrap">
                            <span class="subjectHeader slds-truncate" title="Maths">Maths</span>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" class="subjectHeader slds-cell-wrap">
                            <span class="subjectHeader slds-truncate" title="Computer Science">Computer Science</span>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" class="subjectHeader slds-cell-wrap">
                            <span class="subjectHeader slds-truncate" title="Physics">Physics</span>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" class="subjectHeader slds-cell-wrap">
                            <span class="subjectHeader slds-truncate" title="Maths">Maths</span>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" class="subjectHeader slds-cell-wrap">
                            <span class="subjectHeader slds-truncate" title="Computer Science">Computer Science</span>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" class="subjectHeader slds-cell-wrap">
                            <span class="subjectHeader slds-truncate" title="Physics">Physics</span>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" class="subjectHeader slds-cell-wrap">
                            <span class="subjectHeader slds-truncate" title="Maths">Maths</span>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" class="subjectHeader slds-cell-wrap">
                            <span class="subjectHeader slds-truncate" title="Computer Science">Computer Science</span>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" class="subjectHeader slds-cell-wrap">
                            <span class="subjectHeader slds-truncate" title="Physics">Physics</span>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" class="subjectHeader slds-cell-wrap">
                            <span class="subjectHeader slds-truncate" title="Maths">Maths</span>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" class="subjectHeader slds-cell-wrap">
                            <span class="subjectHeader slds-truncate" title="Computer Science">Computer Science</span>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="slds-hint-parent" style="color:red">
                        <td role="gridcell">1 John</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">1 Doe</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="john.doe@example.com">john.doe@example.com</div>
                        </td>
                        <td role="gridcell">85</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">65</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">65</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">65</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">65</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                        <td role="gridcell">2 Amy</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">2 Williams</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="amy.williams@example.com">amy.williams@example.com</div>
                        </td>
                        <td role="gridcell">65</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">95</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">85</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">65</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">95</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">65</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">95</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">85</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                        <td role="gridcell">3 John</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">3 Williams</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="john.williams@example.com">john.williams@example.com</div>
                        </td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">95</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">85</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">95</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">85</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">95</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">85</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">65</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="slds-hint-parent" style="color:green">
                        <td role="gridcell">4 John</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">4 Baker</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="john.baker@example.com">john.baker@example.com</div>
                        </td>
                        <td role="gridcell">65</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">85</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">95</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">65</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">95</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">65</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">65</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">95</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">85</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">65</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                        <td role="gridcell">5 Robin</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">5 Baker</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="robin.baker@example.com">robin.baker@example.com</div>
                        </td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">95</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">85</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">85</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">95</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">95</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">85</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">65</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                        <td role="gridcell">6 Sarah</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">6 Baker</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="sarah.baker@example.com">sarah.baker@example.com</div>
                        </td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">95</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">85</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">85</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">95</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">65</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">85</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">75</td>
                        <td role="gridcell">65</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```